# Some SQL Server memory consumers keep stealing memory from "Total Server Memory" ? It keep decreasing without any external memory pressure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, memory

**Problem Description** : SQL Server Memory Usage keep increasing while **Total Server Memory** keep **decreasing** till ERROR: **fail_page_allocation** accoured and instance crash

**Version** : SQL Server 2017(RTM-CU21) on Linux

**Runing environment** : K8S 1.18 , Docker 18.09

**Docker Image** : docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-CU21-ubuntu-16.04

**CPU and Memory** : cpu limit 2 , memory limit 4GiB

**Probability of Recurrence** : 100% !

[image]

From the picture , sql server memory usage get from OS keep increasing , and at  a point , CPU usage start fast growing . execute "sp_who2" , and see "RESOUCE MONITOR" consume most of CPU.

The **total_physical_memory** from sys.dm_os_sys_memory  is **3277MB** (which is 80% of 4096)
**Total Server Memory**  from sys.dm_os_performance_counters is **278MB** ,but keep **decreasing** continuously.
**Page life expectancy** is 0-1. And get **process_physical_memory_low = 1**  from sys.dm_os_process_memory.
This situation won't last long , instance crash with  **Error fail_page_allocation 1**.

This is weird ! I konw SQL Server will consume as much memory as it can, but in most case , "Total Server Memory" will grow with "SQL Server memory usage". But in  this case,  it looks like some sql server memory consumers keep stealing memory from "Total Server Memory", but I cant figure out.

There is no link-server , no CLR , no application connections, the only connections are created by Promethues exporter with "go-mssqldb" driver. I search "go-mssqldb" issues but get nothing.

Thanks for reading ! And hope someone can help

post error log here

```
2020-12-30 03:39:08.77 Server      Error: 17300, Severity: 16, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.
2020-12-30 03:39:08.77 spid52
Process/System Counts                         Value
---------------------------------------- ----------
Available Physical Memory                  64430080
Available Virtual Memory                 140733193256960
Available Paging File                      64430080
Working Set                              4294967296
Percent of Committed Memory in WS               100
Page Faults                                       0
System physical memory high                       0
System physical memory low                        0
Process physical memory low                       1
Process virtual memory low                        0
2020-12-30 03:39:08.77 Server      Error: 17312, Severity: 16, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.
2020-12-30 03:39:08.77 Server      Error: 17300, Severity: 16, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.
2020-12-30 03:39:08.77 Server      Error: 17300, Severity: 16, State: 1. (Params:). The error is printed in terse mode because there was error during formatting. Tracing, ETW, notifications etc are skipped.
2020-12-30 03:39:08.78 spid52
Memory Manager                                   KB
---------------------------------------- ----------
VM Reserved                                 4799364
VM Committed                                 202292
Locked Pages Allocated                            0
Large Pages Allocated                             0
Emergency Memory                               1024
Emergency Memory In Use                           8
Target Committed                             202296
Current Committed                            202296
Pages Allocated                              145456
Pages Reserved                                    0
Pages Free                                     8176
Pages In Use                                 192880
Page Alloc Potential                           -696
NUMA Growth Phase                                 2
Last OOM Factor                                   1
Last OS Error                                     0
Memory node Id = 0                               KB
---------------------------------------- ----------
VM Reserved                                 4799236
VM Committed                                 202256
Locked Pages Allocated                            0
Pages Allocated                              145424
Pages Free                                     8208
Target Committed                             202256
Current Committed                            202256
Foreign Committed                                 0
Away Committed                                    0
Taken Away Committed                              0
```

TOP command

```
root@c3d3200-0:/app# top
top - 06:13:37 up 65 days, 22:46,  0 users,  load average: 3.04, 5.44, 5.83
Tasks:   5 total,   1 running,   4 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  5.1 us,  2.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 92.0 id,  0.0 wa,  0.1 hi,  0.4 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 79070835+total, 75951411+free, 21183424 used, 10010844 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 76336390+avail Mem

   PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   435 root      20   0 19.431g 3.226g  24596 S 178.7  0.4  30634:00 sqlservr
     1 root      20   0  131504  18276   8680 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.42 sqlservr
   432 root      20   0   65512   6120   5412 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.41 sshd
245556 root      20   0   19912   3448   3100 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.01 bash
245623 root      20   0   40408   3576   3096 R   0.0  0.0   0:00.13 top
```

Comment: [total server memory] = [database cache] + [stolen memory] + [free memory] — are the dbcache and free counters also available? What is [Max Server Memory] set to for SQL Server, and what was the value of [target server memory] at/near the error? Any use of page space? stolen memory is the kitchen sink - everything that’s not SQL Server dbcache or SQL Server free memory is in there. Does the errorlog contain DBCC Memorystatus results immediately following the fail_page_allocation error?

Comment: [Max Server Memory]  set to default, [target server memory] is near 200MB when error accoure. I post the error log, it contain DBCC Memorystatus results

Comment: I post the error log, it contain DBCC Memorystatus results . when i say some consumer steal memory from [total server memory] ,i didn't mean  [stolen memory] ,but something out of the control of [total server memory] or [Max Server Memory]

Comment: When SQL Server can achieve [Max Server Memory] based on memory used by other consumers, that value will serve as [Target Server Memory]. Otherwise a lower attainable value will be used. Workload activity can cause [total server memory] to grow to target, or SQL Server can shrink caches and the buffer pool to shrink total to target if needed. The ~200 mb target is the reason for ~200 mb [total server memory] here. SQL Server thinks there are outside consumers of memory. Could it be filesystem cache?

Comment: "SQL Server thinks there are outside consumers of memory." SQL Server run in docker ,and the only process run in docker is SQL Server . I post the TOP command result above . it is weird that "sqlservr" consume 3.2g, but the "Target Server Memory" is only 200m.

Comment: is a single docker image running? if so, when the SQL Server service is stopped, does ipcs-m still show shared memory segments belonging to SQL Server? i wonder if shared memory segments became orphaned from their owning process in the past.

Comment: What was the docker run statement you used to deploy SQL Server? Can you give us the output of docker stats?

Comment: @sqL_handLe Could it be SQL Server thread stacks memory?  docker cpu limit 2 , but "lscpu" in docker, it returns 64, which is the logical CPU num. so, SQL Server will resume 2MB*(512+(64-4)*16) for thread stacks memory , which is about 2.8GB.

Comment: i wouldn’t expect it to be worker-thread related. SQL Server starts with a base number of user workers and will increase the count on demand. After ~15 minutes of idle, excess workers are terminated and count could go all the way down to base. In Windows there is no memory reservation for the thread-private 2 mb before the worker itself is started - i expect that same behavior in Linux. Also - if it were early reservation for max workers if wouldn’t increase over time as appears to happen here.